# How to find every Tuesday week based on particular date range along with it's value using some defined logic

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, lubridate

for any particular date range, I need to take

mean of all the 1st week Tuesday of every month
mean of all the 2nd week Tuesday of every month
mean of all the 3rd week Tuesday of every month

for the 4th week Tuesday and 5th week Tuesday , the logic needs to be such that
if the month has only 4 Tuesday then take is as Final week, However if the month has 5 week
then logic needs to be followed as below

If the month has 5th Tuesday which is the last week of the month for march and june, 
and other month has 4 week as their last week which is for feb , april and may
then take mean of(5th week March + 4th Week Feb + 4th week April)
and take mean of 4th week for every months which has 5 week separately

replicate code

```
dates_seq<-(seq(as.Date("2020/02/01"), by = "day", length.out = 152))
dates_seq<-as.data.frame(dates_seq)
values<-seq(1:152)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(dates_seq,values))
```

manual approach

```
temp <- subset(df, dates_seq >= as.Date('2020-02-01') & 
                 dates_seq <= as.Date('2020-06-30'))
temp$week_day <- weekdays(temp$dates_seq)
temp$week_number <- ave(temp$week_day, temp$week_day, format(temp$StartOfWeekDt, "%Y-%m"), FUN = seq_along)


week1<-subset(temp, (week_number == 1 & week_day == 'Tuesday' |
                     week_number == 5 & week_day == 'Tuesday' |
                     week_number == 10 & week_day == 'Tuesday'|
                     week_number == 14 & week_day == 'Tuesday'|
                     week_number == 18 & week_day == 'Tuesday') )
week1_avg=mean(week1$values);
week1
```

I tried this way but it is a very manual approach and when dates changes the above condition also changes

output is provided in below link

https://ibb.co/BcsC7Rt

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Shan R I would appreciate if you can help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this gets you the result. Note that nth value "NA" is your "Last Tuesdays". See if it tests good.

```
    df %>%
  filter(wday(dates_seq) == 2) %>%
  mutate(Month = month(dates_seq)) %>%
  arrange(dates_seq) %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  mutate (nth = ifelse(Month < lead(Month, default = last(Month)), 99, 1:5)) %>%
  mutate (nth = ifelse((nth > lead(nth)), 99, nth)) %>%
  group_by(nth) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(values))
```

Comment: could you explain this line lead(Month, default = last(Month)), 99, 1:5) and why are we using 99 ?

Comment: It is a dummy value. I originally had a number for comparing. You can change both 99 to NA and the code will work.

Comment: Did it help? If so, consider "accepting" the solution by clicking the grey checkmark next to the answer.